# How to Select value By SuiteQL That I can filter Multiple Select Field

Tags: sql, netsuite, suitescript, ansi-sql-92, suiteql

I had one simple table ItemMapping, 2 Field, one Field is single Item List Field SingleSelectField With value "A",
Other for Multiple Item List Field MultiSelectField with Value ("B", "C", "D").

I Wanna get This mapping relationship By "B", I tried to set up one dataset, And try some single SuiteQL like before, But I always get empty results returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemMapping
WHERE ItemMapping.MultiSelectField IN ('B')
```

Any tips may Help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Below is the same problem for us, We are not able to filter the multi Select Field Value By Origin SuiteQL Provided By NetSuite System.
[link](http://5.9.10.113/67771794/suiteql-error-element-does-not-exist-or-element-class-sqlpredicate-is-expected)

Comment: Just ran across this tonight

Comment: I believe Marty Zigman had solved the problem, you may reference by [this link](https://blog.prolecto.com/2021/08/21/learn-how-to-sql-query-netsuite-multiple-select-fields/)

Answer (score 7):

As was pointed out, Marty Zigman's [article](https://blog.prolecto.com/2021/08/21/learn-how-to-sql-query-netsuite-multiple-select-fields/) describes how Boban D. located an undocumented "feature" of SuiteQL which can be used.

I will leave most of the explaining to the article but to summarize, NetSuite automatically creates a relationship table named map_*sourcTableId*_*fieldId* which contain two columns: *mapone* and *maptwo*. *mapone* is the record id from the source table and *maptwo* is record id for the joined table.

This method seems to work well and maybe the most straight forward if you are accustomed to working in SQL.

As an alternative, I constructed a native SuiteScript `Query` object with a condition on a multiple select field. Then I used the `toSuiteQL()` method to convert it into SuiteQL to see how NetSuite natively deals with this. What I found was another undocumented "feature". The resulting query used a `BUILTIN.MNFILTER` function. So for example if you've got a custom transaction body field, `custbody_link_type`, that is a multiple select field and want to get transactions where one of te values in `custbody_link_type` is `4` then here is the generated SuiteQL:

```sql
SELECT T.tranid, T.custbody_link_types 
FROM "transaction" as T
WHERE BUILTIN.MNFILTER(T.custbody_link_types , 'MN_INCLUDE', '', 'FALSE', NULL, 4) = 'T'
```

And if you want transactions where the `custbody_link_types` does not contain all of the following: 1, 2, 3 ...

```sql
SELECT T.tranid, T.custbody_link_types 
FROM "transaction" as T
WHERE BUILTIN.MNFILTER(T.custbody_link_types , 'MN_EXCLUDE_ALL', '', 'FALSE', NULL, 1, 2, 3) = 'T'
  OR T.custbody_link_types IS NULL
```

To wrap it up, the undocumented `BUILTIN.MNFILTER` function is used by NetSuite's query module to filter multiple select fields. It accepts the multiple select column, the internal string value of the `query.Operator` enum, some other stuff I don't know anything about, and finally one or more the values to compare. It appears to return a string of either 'T' for when the condition is met otherwise 'F'.

Ultimately, I'm not sure whether this is a "better" way to address the need but I thought it was worth documenting.

Comment: I have a question, when I use this `BUILTIN.MNFILTER`. I get results back that don't have a column value at all, is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @Webdeveloper_Jelle, if I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying that the `BUILTIN.MNFILTER` is return 'T' when the multiselect value is empty. If this true, I'm not entirely sure what to say. Given the undocumented nature of this function, I don't know how to modify parameters to get better results and functionality might have changed since I posted this. I'd recommend trying to generate what you want with the SuiteScript `Query` API and see how it converts to SuiteQL.