# SuiteQL Join to a Multi-Select Field

Tags: sql, netsuite, suiteql

I'm trying to write a SuiteQl statement that will join my item table to a custom record that has a multi-select field including the item id.

select item.id from item
JOIN CUSTOMRECORD_REBATE_AGREEMENT_DETAIL cr on cr.custrecord_rebate_items_included = item.id

Comment: You have not actually asked a question...?

Comment: I want to know how I can join my item table to the custom table?

Comment: Please provide a mre https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Item table: itemid
CUSTOMRECORD_REBATE_AGREEMENT_DETAIL  table: custrecord_rebate_items_included column which has multiple item ids.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852393/how-to-select-value-by-suiteql-that-i-can-filter-multiple-select-field)

```
select
item.id, map.*, BUILTIN.DF(mapone), BUILTIN.DF(maptwo), BUILTIN.DF(custrecord_tier_group), custrecord_rip_code
     FROM
item
        JOIN
           map_CUSTOMRECORD_REBATE_AGREEMENT_DETAIL_custrecord_rebate_items_included map
           ON map.mapone = item.id 
JOIN CUSTOMRECORD_REBATE_AGREEMENT_DETAIL cr on cr.id = map.mapone
JOIN customrecord_rebate_agreement ca on cr.custrecord_rebate_parent  = ca.id
```